# WCF client authentication on server side

Tags: wcf, authentication, impersonation

I have such structure on my client.

```
WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
IntPtr token = wi.Token;
```

Next step is send authentication token to server through WCF and impersonate user there.

```
api.SendToken(token);

...
...
...
```

But as soon I receive token on server side and trying to build WindowsIdentity it throws me an error:

```
WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(token);

Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated.
```

Could you guys please help me to figure out what I am doing wrong and share your ideas how do I pass token from client to server.

Thanks!

Comment: Is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751480.aspx helpful?

Answer (score 1):

WCF already has built-in plumbing to support [Windows impersonation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090.aspx) Is there is a reason you're trying to roll your own?

UPDATE to avoid link-only answers (ahhh, errors of my youth...)

Here are the basic steps needed to configure the built in WCF impersonation

- Only some bindings support Windows authentication. The WSHttpBinding is the most common one to support it but others may support it too.
- On the service contract, use the OperationBehavior attribute on the method that requires impersonation:

  ```
  [OperationBehavior(Impersonation=ImpersonationOption.Required)]
  public string SomeMethod(string aParameter) { ... }
  ```
- For the client, it is simplest to create a custom class inheriting from the ClientBase class. All service reference types inherit from this class. Here is an example of the client code:

  ```
  var client = new SomeClientBaseDerivedType("TheServiceEndpoint");
  client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel =
      System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
  ```